# `require': cannot load such file -- oj (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I only know the basics of the Ruby and trying to fix this error. There were same questions already but couldn't get it solved from those.

When I run following command in my Ruby Project

```
rerun 'ruby app.rb'
```

I got the following error.

```
[rerun] Webhook-receiver launched

/Users/myhome/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/
rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:
in `require': cannot load such file -- oj (LoadError)

from  /Users/myhome/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/
core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:
in `require' from app.rb:2:in `<main>'

[rerun] Webhook-receiver Launch Failed
[rerun] Watching . for **/*.{rb,js,coffee,css,scss,sass,erb,html,haml,ru,yml,slim,md,feature}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to install oj gem or add it to Gemfile if you use bundler?

Comment: Hi @user3309314, thanks. I am using bundler. Can you please help me how can I add oj gem to Gemfile?

Comment: Start here: http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html

Comment: Awesome I just did `bundle install` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @orde, that's a great explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with the intention of providing a detailed and structured answer for others, since you have already solved the issue. When developing a Ruby application, if code that lives in an external gem is required, you can use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to keep track and manage your dependencies. It uses a file called [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.16/man/gemfile.5.html) to register the dependencies that your project relies on, as well as the source from where these dependencies will be pulled to your machine. A basic syntax example of Gemfile.

```
# Registering the sources of gem packages
source 'https://rubygems.org'
[...]

# Requiring a gem for this project
gem 'package_1' # registers a dependency
gem 'package_2', '>=2.0.0' # registers a dependency, with minimum version required
gem 'package_3', '>= 1.5.0', '< 1.9.0' # registers a dependency, with minimum and maximum version required
[...]
```

With all this set up, when you run [bundle install](http://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-install.1.html), the dependencies that are specified in your gemfile are pulled to your machine and you can run the program. If you want to check more information for a gem on your machine, you can run [bundle info package](http://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-info.1.html) (below an example for mysql gem)

```
  * mysql (2.9.1)
    Summary: This is the MySQL API module for Ruby
    Homepage: http://github.com/luislavena/mysql-gem
    Path: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1
```

Comment: That is brilliant explanation. Thank you so much @danieldeveloper001

Comment: You're more than welcome, glad that I could help you, please, let me know if there is something more that you want to know. Regards :)